# isotope can't be called on jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

My page loads with both the jQuery and isotope libraries.

From the console I can build a function that calls isotope on a DOM element.

However, if I do jQuery('.el').isotope, then I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).isotope is not a function(…)

However, the home page for isotope clearly states that isotope can be used  on jQuery selectors.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it loads after jQuery ? Are you sure its compatible with the jQuery version ?

Comment: Or loading jquery twice will cause this. Start in browser dev tools network and see what actually gets loaded and in what order

Comment: You need to provide more information. Post your code and a link or jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes: I'm 100% sure that the page is loading jQuery once.